# How to properly deduce a dereferenced type of the iterator returned from std::set::begin()?

Tags: c++

I have a template class with container type defined as a StorageType template.

```
StorageType mStorage;
....
void iterate( const std::function<bool( typename StorageType::value_type& )>& aFnc )
{
    for( auto it = mStorage.begin(); it != mStorage.end(); ++it )
    {
        aFnc( *it );
    }
}
```

This works for the most of the stl containers. But when it comes to std::set I am facing an issue because mStorage.begin() returns const_iterator and aFnc( *it ) compilation fails as aFnc function expects StorageType::value_type& which is non-const.

I have tried to deduce a proper type by getting the result of std::set::begin and deducing the dereferenced type of the iterator received by that, that was looking like:

```
void iterate( std::function<void(typename std::iterator_traits<std::result_of<decltype(&std::set<ValueType>::begin)(std::set<ValueType>)>::type>::value_type& )>& aFnc )
```

But seems that std::iterator_traits<>::value_type returns non-const value type regardless the fact that real iterator from std::set::begin() dereferences to const T&.

My goal is to deduce a proper signature of the function provided as an argument. Everything will compile for std::set if I will define mentioned function as ( const std::function& aFnc ), but will not work for other container types like vector.

Comment: What's the definition of `StorageType`?

Comment: A `std::set` doesn't allow modification of its elements in place. From C++17 on you can use the `extract` member function, but that is a different approach that doesn't match the one you posted. In any case, when would you want to inject `std::vector` or `std::set` interchangeably? I don't see a reasonable use case, those are completely different containers.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher it is a template argument.

Comment: Indeed, should be a const&, not just a &...

Comment: @lubgr I know it doesn't allow modifications. My goal is to deduce a proper signature of the function provided as an argument. Everything will compile for set if I will define it as ( const std::function<bool( const typename StorageType::value_type& )>& aFnc ), but will not work for other container types like vector.

Comment: What's the error for vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `std::function` here. Just let `aFnc` be a deduced template parameter.

```
template <typename Func>
void iterate( Func aFnc )
{
    for( auto & obj : mStorage )
    {
        aFnc( obj );
    }
}
```

Or

```
template <typename Func>
void iterate( Func && aFnc )
{
    std::for_each( mStorage.begin(), mStorage.end(), std::forward<Func>(aFnc) );
}
```

Comment: It is a solution indeed. I am already using this function in many places and in case I will introduce a template argument I will have to change hundred of places.

Comment: @teoring no, you don't need to change the call site. Function template arguments can be deduced.

Comment: Shouldn't I change the function call from iterate( aFnc) to iterate<>( aFnc ) in order to compile? I think I do.

Comment: @teoring No, you don't need to. `iterate<>( aFnc )` means the same as `iterate( aFnc)` in that context.

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is an acceptable solution for me. For some reason, though I will have to specify a template brackets.

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` doesn't allow to modify the elements via iterators. Both `std::set::iterator` and `std::set::const_iterator` are constant iterators (may even be the same type). This is because `std::set` must be not allow duplicates.

So no matter what type deduction witchery it is simply not possible to modify elements of the `set` in this kind of for iteration. If `aFnc` needs to modify elements you can't use `std::set`.

If instead `aFnc` doesn't modify its arguments then you need to make the arg const:

```
using StoredType = typename StorageType::value_type;

void iterate(const std::function<bool(const StoredType&)>& aFnc)
```